# How to put a value and a text in an excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data:

```
net profit   cum. profit
10         10
20         30
20         50
20         70
20         90
```

cum.profit(current cell) =net profit (in the same row) + cum. profit (previous cell).
Now ıf my cum. profit exceeds 100 I wish the current  cum. profit cell to display the "value" as well as a text like" you have exceeded 100". I use:

```
=IF(I55+H56<100,I55+H56,"STOP")
```

so, if I55+H56 is less than 100 the cell is filled value I55+H56, else the text value "STOP" is written into the cell. But I want the value also to be written into that cell. i.e something like 100,STOP.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
IF(I55+H56<100,I55+H56,(I55+H56)&",STOP")
```

Comment: @cumhuratilgan. If puneet's answer addresses properly your question, please consider accepting it (green checkmark under the answer's vote arrows).

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value in the cell to remain a number (i.e. to allow calculations on the row) you can use a custom format.

just use this in your cell: `=I55+H56`

Right click and select "Format cells".

Then go to Custom format and type: `[>=100]0", Stop";0`

The result will be `120, Stop` for a value equal to 120.